# how to chance sprite sneaky joystick (Dpad)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

im trying to chance te sprite when i move my sprite, ik got left up and down working but not right. here is my code:

```
if (dpad.degrees > 0 && dpad.degrees < 59) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerrigt.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going rigt");
}
else if (dpad.degrees > 331 && dpad.degrees < 360) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerrigt.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going rigt");
}
else if (dpad.degrees > 151 && dpad.degrees < 240) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerleft.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going left");
}
if (dpad.degrees > 60 && dpad.degrees < 150) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerup.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going up");
}
else if (dpad.degrees > 241 && dpad.degrees < 330) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerdown.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going down");
}
```

and yes i know i speld right wrong XD.

thx for ur time.

Comment: No idea, but you do have 'missing' ranges in there.. (i.e. if dpad.degrees == 0, or >=59 && <=60 , etc..). Maybe that's your issue? if 'right' is zero degrees, it's currently uncaught by any of the cases there.

Comment: some how if i set it == 0 it runs the code whine i don't touch the dpad. i have try'd all ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if figurd it out by doing somting diferent.
first i added an new CGPoint

```
CGPoint oldPosition = ccp(player.position.x, player.position.y);
```

then i used the difference in old and new position

```
  if (oldPosition.x < newPosition.x) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerrigt.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going rigt");
}
else if (oldPosition.x > newPosition.x) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerleft.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going left");
}
if (oldPosition.y < newPosition.y) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerup.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going up");
}
else if (oldPosition.y > newPosition.y) {
    [player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerdown.png"]];
    NSLog(@"going down");
}
```

hope it helps someone who has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

First, set the joystick to DPad type and 4 directions

```
    joystick.isDPad=YES;
    joystick.numberOfDirections=4;
```

in the update:

```
    CGPoint velocity = ccpMult(joystick.velocity, 100);
    if(velocity.x!=0||velocity.y!=0)
    if(abs(velocity.x)>50&&abs(velocity.y)>50)
    {
        return;
    }
   else if(velocity.x < -50)
    {
        //code for go left here
        return;
    }
    else if(velocity.x > 50)
{
     //code for go right here
    return;
}

    else if(velocity.y > 50)
    {
        //code for go up here
        return;
    }else if(velocity.y < -50)
    {
         //code for go down here
        return;
    }
```